# Revalidating nextjs within existing api route

Tags: next.js

I'm confused about why so many of the examples for NextJS revalidation use a separate endpoint for revalidation. Is that because some folks set up some polling to revalidate via that endpoint?

For my use case, I have a route and when the user makes an update to it I want to call revalidate... But I would rather not have to call `fetch` and make a separate call and just use the existing `NextApiResponse` object to revalidate the route. Is this a bad practice for some reason?

Comment: [On-demand revalidation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration#using-on-demand-revalidation) has to occur inside an API route because that's where `res.revalidate` is available from. You can call that from an existing API route if you'd prefer, that's really up to you. Just keep in mind that you may want to prevent unauthorized access to the revalidation logic.

Comment: @juliomalves if my revalidate happens from within existing routes that are already authenticated then hypothetically there is no downside?

Comment: Hypothetically, that should be fine.